# How do I get a foreign key's field using Retrofit and Gson?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an api endpoint which outputs this json for an event table

```
{
    "name": "",
    "time": null,
    "event_pic_url": null,
    "description": "",
    "event_type": null,
    "invite_only": false,
    "free": false,
    "age_restriction": false,
    "ticket_price": null,
    "venue": null
}
```

The venue field is a foreign key to a Venue table that has this format.

```
{
    "name": "",
    "rating": null,
    "longitude": null,
    "latitude": null
}
```

After getting the list of events, I would like to get them on a recyclerview (I can already get the list and know how to use an adapter)but I don't want to show the venue's {id}, I want to use the venue's {name}. How do I do this? Is it related to how nested json is deserialized?

Comment: Depends... I have a couple of questions, then I might be able to help. Are you using Retrofit with Gson? Is your rest api actually returning the jsons above or is that the result of the serialization? I mean, is it possible that the server doesn't even send you the nested json? Do you already have some models?

Comment: Yes I am using retrofit with Gson. The rest api returns the json as I have shown above. It does not send nested json.

Comment: Ok, retrofit won't do this for you out of the box. You have 2 options, find out if the first call supports some parameters, or headers that would tell the server he should also include the ``venue`` json in the response. If so then it would be easier to help out. If not, then you have to find out how you can get that ``venue``'s id, because most probably you'll have to make another rest call. I'd go with the first approach, try and figure out if you can include the ``venue``'s body in the first call's response. Let me know, I'll help you further.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by " find out if the first call supports some parameters, or headers that would tell the server he should also include the venue find out if the first call supports some parameters, or headers that would tell the server he should also include the venue" could you give me an example of such a header or parameter?

Comment: That depends on the API you're calling, and nobody but the people in charge of it could answer that question.  If you are the one in charge of the endpoint, then change it to return the venue with the event.

Comment: @zacmwa like @nasch points out that depends on your api. For example with the one I'm currently working with, we can make a call, say ``/event/1/`` and add a parameter to include the venue - ``/event/1/?includes[]=venue``. But this depends on the API. By the looks of yours there should be a way, because most probably the server wouldn't include a null "venue" if there wasn't. Unless of course the event has no venue yet.

Comment: @Fred I decided to change the api to output nested json because after searching I couldn't find anything else.

Comment: ok, so do you still need help? Now I could post you the answer on how to get that.

Comment: @Fred  Yes that would be very helpful. I have just finished altering backend so I can get  nested json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the comments I will assume that now you have something like:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "time": null,
  "event_pic_url": null,
  "description": "",
  "event_type": null,
  "invite_only": false,
  "free": false,
  "age_restriction": false,
  "ticket_price": null,
  "venue": {
     "name": "",
     "rating": null,
     "longitude": null,
     "latitude": null
  }
}
```

Since you're using `Gson`, you'll want to have the following models

```
public class Venue {

  @SerializedName("name")
  @Expose
  private String name;
  @SerializedName("rating")
  @Expose
  private Integer rating;
  @SerializedName("longitude")
  @Expose
  private Double longitude;
  @SerializedName("latitude")
  @Expose
  private Double latitude;

  // ...
}

public class Event {

  @SerializedName("name")
  @Expose
  private String name;
  @SerializedName("time")
  @Expose
  private String time;
  @SerializedName("event_pic_url")
  @Expose
  private String eventPicUrl;
  @SerializedName("description")
  @Expose
  private String description;
  @SerializedName("event_type")
  @Expose
  private String eventType;
  @SerializedName("invite_only")
  @Expose
  private Boolean inviteOnly;
  @SerializedName("free")
  @Expose
  private Boolean free;
  @SerializedName("age_restriction")
  @Expose
  private Boolean ageRestriction;
  @SerializedName("ticket_price")
  @Expose
  private Double ticketPrice;
  @SerializedName("venue")
  @Expose
  private Venue venue;
  // ...
}
```

Please note that I'm assuming some data types here, i.e., for `latitude` and `longitude` as well as `event_type`. Since in the json they were `null` I couldn't really be sure, but I guess you can understand from this example. Also please add the appropriate getters and setters.

I want you to focus on the `venue` part. As you see I'm basically recreating the "nested" json part in Java objects. And that's just it, `Gson` and `retrofit` will do the rest for you. Here's how. A word of caution - This may vary a lot depending on how you're doing things. I prefer `rxjava`, but I'll use the callback approach here since it's easier to explain.

Retrofit **1.9** you can do:

```
public interface EventService {
   @GET("/url/to/events/endpoint/")
   public void get(Callback<Event> callback);
}
```

Provided everything goes well, on the `success` method of your callback you'll get an instance of `Event` where you can access the `Venue` object provided the returned json is actually the one above.

Retrofit **2** the interface changes a bit, but essentially it's the same idea as before:

```
public interface EventService {
   @GET("/url/to/events/endpoint/")
   public Call<Event> get();
}
```

Once you `enqueue` the request and define the `Callback` object you will also get an `Event` object in your success method that would have a reference to a venue. Here's how these callbacks might be implemented with Retrofit **2** (Might slightly change between retrofit versions. I don't fully remember):

```
eventService.get().enqueue(new Callback<Event>() {
  @Override public void onResponse(Call<Event> call, Response<Event> response) {
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
      // Handle http error
      return;
    }

    Event event = response.body();
    Venue venue = event.getVenue();

    // do something with it
  }

  @Override public void onFailure(Call<Event> call, Throwable t) {
    // Handle error
  }
 });
}
```

Here `eventService` is an object created by `Retrofit.create(EventService.class)`.

Again the retrofit bit might change depending which method you want to use. Important is to understand how you map from the json response to the java objects and basically you just need to replicate the same json structure but in java objects. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi. I was able to change my retrofit code so that I can make desrialize the nested json but now I am having a problem binding the venue name to a textview. After getting the nested response when I try to set text like this: holder.eventVenueTextView.setText(event.getVenue().getName()), I get a java.lang.NullPointerException which points me to the line above. The non nested fields are working fine it's just the venue name that is not working. I followed your other steps and  when I log the response in retrofit I can see a response that has the venue

Comment: Hey, could you maybe update your question or point me to a link where you have your code? I'm guessing there might be a small disparity between the java models and the json. It would also be very helpful if you could also put the new json response.

Comment: Thanks.I was able to solve the problem. I had not added the converter factory but when I did everything worked fine.